# Issues in upgrading from Magento 2.1.10 to 2.2.0

Tags: sql, magento2.2.0, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from **Magento 2.1.10 to 2.2.0** but I am getting the below error when running:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 , query was: ALTER TABLE `eav_attribute_group` ADD UNIQUE `CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CODE` (`attribute_set_id`,`attribute_group_code`)

I'm not great with SQL so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my opinion, don't go to 2.2.1 go to 2.1.10. But... have you updated your composer.json to get to 2.2 ? Please provide a few more steps you have completed before this. Also first think about going to 2.2 then to 2.2.1

Comment: Thanks Andy. Steps were: disable cache, then: 'composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 --no-update', then 'composer update' which is where I am getting the error.

Comment: Have managed to get from 2.1.6 to 2.1.10 but then get the same error as above when going from 2.1.10 to 2.2.0.